# Data is cutting when importing huge data i.e more than 255 characters from Excel cell into SQL server 2008

Tags: asp.net

I am using Asp.net web application for importing the data from Excel cells into SQL server 2008. but while importing some data is perfectly imported but some cells data is cutting. due to that some data is lost. please give solution for this issue.

I think it is not imported the data which is having large size i.e greater than 255 characters. Please let me know the solution for importing the large size cell data.

Comment: You will have to show us your table schema, the code doing the upload, and which columns are being affected.

Comment: string strConnection = "Data Source=Admin-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Abc;Integrated Security=sspi";
        
string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\aaa.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
            
OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
            
                                                         OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [q_id],[q_desc] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you table schema may be causing this. Make sure that the fields you are importing the data to have an appropriate size. e.g. you may be trying to commit a string of 300 characters to a `varchar(255)` column.

Comment: no no. i am using nvarchar(MAX) data type for that column in my Table but at the time of importing itself it gives only 255 characters.